# Shim DbContext ctor for Effort unit testing

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes, shim, effort

I'd like to intercept `var context = new MyDbContext()` to return a different constructor call instead.

The great thing about [EFfort](https://github.com/tamasflamich/effort) is that it let's you set up an easy in-memory database for unit testing.

```
var connection = Effort.DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient();
var testContext = new MyDbContext(connection);
```

But then you'd have to inject that `context` into your repository.

```
public FooRepository(MyDbContext context) { _context = context; }
```

Is it possible to just intercept `var context = new MyDbContext()` , so that it returns the `testContext`?

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext()) {
    // this way, my code isn't polluted with a ctor just for testing
}
```

Comment: You have two possible options. Using factories or via Aspect oriented programming (like PostSharp) check this article: http://www.progware.org/Blog/post/Interception-and-Interceptors-in-C-(Aspect-oriented-programming).aspx

Comment: Good tips, but in the end I found a way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(edit: I just realized this isn't actually returning the other ctor call. working on it.)*

Figured it out.  Simple enough if you know how to do it:

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void Should_have_a_name_like_this()
        {
            // Arrange
            var connection = Effort.DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient();
            ShimSolrDbContext.Constructor = context => new SolrDbContext(connection);

            // Act


            // Assert

        }
```

And as usual, EFfort requires this constructor in the DbContext class:

```
public class SomeDbContext
{
    public SomeDbContext() : base("name=Prod")
    {
    }

    // EFfort unit testing ctor
    public SomeDbContext(DbConnection connection) : base(connection, contextOwnsConnection: true) {
        Database.SetInitializer<SolrDbContext>(null);
    }
}
```

But it means the repo is blissfully unaware of the special Transient connection:

```
public class SomeRepository
{
    public void SomeMethodName()
    {
        using (var context = new SomeDbContext())
        {
            // self-contained in repository, no special params
            // and still calls the special test constructor
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two possible options. Using factories or via Aspect oriented programming (like PostSharp)

referencing this article: http://www.progware.org/Blog/post/Interception-and-Interceptors-in-C-(Aspect-oriented-programming).aspx

#### Using PostSharp (AOP)

> PostSharp is a great tool and can achieve the most clean interception
> possible (meaning no changes in your classes and object generation at
> all even if you do not your factories for object creation and/or
> interfaces) but it is not a free library. Rather than creating proxies
> at runtime, it injects code at compile time and therefore changes your
> initial program in a seamless way to add method interception.
> .....
> The cool thing in this is that you do not change anything else in your
> code, so your object can be still generated using the new keyword.

#### Using DI and Factory-pattern

I personally prefer the factory-pattern approach, but you seem apposed to having to inject any dependencies into your classes.

```
public interface IDbContextFactory<T> where T : DbContext {
    T Create();
}

public class TestDbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> {
    public MyDbContext Create() {
        var connection = Effort.DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient();
        var testContext = new MyDbContext(connection);
        return testContext;
    }
}

public class FooRepository {
    MyDbContext _context;
    public FooRepository(IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> factory) { 
        _context = factory.Create(); 
    }
}
```